# I am trying to render the names on my screen using "Rick and Morty" REST API,but nothing literally renders and my state is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I am using an API called "Rick and Morty Rest API", it is based on really popular TV show, I am trying to render names of the character on the screen, but nothing is showing up.

My code for App.js is below:

```
    state = {
    url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character",
    character: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({
      character: res.data.results.forEach(function(element) {
        return element.name;
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
           <h1>{this.state.character}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What i have tried to do:

1. I have set my "state" to two parameters called url and character.
2. Using setState i am trying to update my state's character to name(I have a list of names, that is why I have used forEach)
3. Finally in the "h1" tag i am trying to render the UPDATED STATE character
4. I am getting not getting an error and absolutely is rendering on my screen.

I have pushed everything as it is to my github for more reference: https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/Rick-and-Morty-Database

API link which i am using: https://rickandmortyapi.com/

Comment: try to console.log(res) before updating the state and see what you get. are you sure you getting the response you're expecting? becaus eyour code seems quite alright. 
and out of curiosity- why using componentDidMount and not componentWillMount? sounds more logical to fetch data and render it with the component when it goes up, not when its done loading and then you need to re-render it

Comment: componentWillMount has been deprecated and is not recommended, similar functionality can be done using constructor inside componentDidMount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the state variable `character`, as an array:

```
  state = {
    url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character",
    character: []
  };
```

Instead of using `forEach`, hold the results in your state.

```
this.setState({
          character: res.data.results
    });
```

Then map the results inside render, like this:

```
{this.state.character.map(character => {
       return(
         <h1>{character.name}</h1>
       )
   })}
```

Comment: you did not really answer his question... why is it different than what he does? I mean, it will render each char in a different h1 tag, but it still does not explain why nothing is being rendered now. If the problem is elsewhere, or he intentionally wanted it that way, than the solution won't be of much use.

Comment: @Gibor `forEach` does not return anything, that is the problem. Replace you `forEach`, with `map` it will work that way too.

Comment: the steps suggested by @user9408899 are the same thing in a different way what i did. However, when i tried to replace "null" by "[]" it did the work, and now i'm getting rendered list on my screen. Thanks !!

Comment: I just wonder why leaving null is wrong as i'm updating the state with new values anyway

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul you say that even if you stick with the `forEach`, just replacing null with [] does the job?

Comment: No sorry, I wanted to say I have replaced forEach with map() also and it did the work along with initializing character with an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate through every element while setting the state, which is why you are unable to render anything as your state is still undefined at the end of the loop. Always use alternatives in such scenarios, such as using spread operators or concatenation. In your case, it can be like this:

```
this.setState({
character: res.data.results
})
```

After that iterate through your character array using any helper method (map, forEach etc). 
It's not compulsory to assign your character to empty array in your state, but it's always a good practice to make the same type of variable/array/object in state, which you are expecting to use later in your code. As for now, your `character: null` would also work fine.